# Why can't a static nested class access "this" pointer of outer class?

Tags: java, class, nested-class, static-classes

[image]

The thing that bothers me is the second point.

I thought it might have to do with the fact that the "this" pointer isn't static and so the inner class can't access it. I'm not sure if that's the right explanation though.

This also raised another question for me which was "where is the "this" pointer defined?"

Comment: Imagine using `TopClass.this` in a `static` method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference between a `static` nested class and one that isn't `static` is precisely that an instance of a non-`static` inner class is associated with a specific instance of the enclosing class, while a `static` inner class isn't. There *is* no `A.this` for an instance of a `static` inner class to be associated with.

Comment: One more thing, when you say that an inner class is associated with a specific instance of the enclosing class, does that mean that I can change the instance it is associated with?

Comment: No, you can't; its `ParentClass.this` reference is assigned when it's created, and that's that.

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it by clicking the check box on the left.

Answer (score 2):

If an inner class is `static` then it can be instantiated without an enclosing instance of the outer class. For a non-`static` inner class an instance of the outer class is required for instantiation. For example, if your class structure is this :

```
public class A {
    public static class B {
    }

    public class C {
    }
}
```

then to instantiate `B` and `C` you would have to do it like this :

```
// simply
A.B b = new A.B();
// however
A.C c = new A().new C();
```

Behind the scenes when a non-`static` inner class is instantiated an instance of the enclosing class is passed into the constructor. The instance of `OuterClass.this` is then accessible because of this.

To verify the "behind the scenes" thing you can check the declared constructors and declared fields of the inner class via reflection:

```
// prints that there is one field of type A called "this$1"
for (Field f : A.C.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    System.out.println(f);
}

// prints that the constructor takes in one parameter of type A
for (Constructor c : A.C.class.getDeclaredConstructors()) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```